# Number of subgroups of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, quantum-information

I came across this statement on page 24 of [these notes](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Edenis/notes16.pdf#page33):

[Every finite group] G has $\leq |G|^{\log |G|}$ subgroups (because every subgroup has at most $\log |G|$ generators).

I figured out why the part in parentheses is true, but I’ve been having trouble seeing why the main statement follows from that fact. I’ve searched for a while but have only seen the bound mentioned as “trivial” in some more advanced papers, so I’m guessing it’s an elementary fact in finite group theory that I don’t have the background in to see. If anyone could clarify the bound a bit that would be great.

Comment: It's an elementary fact in combinatorics rather than group theory. There are $|G|^{\lfloor \log |G| \rfloor}$ ordered sequences  of elements of $G$ of length $\lfloor \log |G| \rfloor$.

Comment: Aa right of course… I feel a bit silly now but that is part of learning. Thanks for the comment!